# How heavily are the 'Mind Cleansed' affected by their 'Shards of Memory'?

Tags: character-creation, dark-heresy-1e

**Quick backstory:**

In an old game, I played an Explorator by the name of 'Hadden Torian'. This character, through his adventures, became ever so slightly insane (*cough*); through his exposure to the warp, conversing with a (somehow) sentient ex-Psyker Servo Skull, and psychic adventures that his binary-logic mind failed to comprehend. It got to the point where he considered committing Tech-Heresy by converting the skull of a Kroot bodyguard into a Servo Skull.

**Present Day:**

The game has been re-born, everyone is creating new characters, and I was given the opportunity to re-create Hadden. He is now one of the 'Mind Cleansed', with all the bells and whistles - failsafe controls, eroding sanity, and the aptly named 'Shards of Memory'. All-in-all fairly fitting for a lobotomized Tech-Priest verging on Tech-Heresy.

**The question:**

How much of an effect do these 'Shards of Memory' have on the character? I would assume it'd be primarily up to the GM, but is there any specific set of rules that define when/what effect this has on the character (Eg. on a failed sanity check, you have to roll another sanity check or gain (x) sanity points)? Or is it just a bit of backstory that changes how the character might function in the world (Eg. triggers determined by the GM create episodes that the affected has to deal with; mini psychotic episodes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Shards of Memory' table is more of a flavor text addition with no mechanical impact. It's for plot hooks or determining more about how you role-play your character.

> **Shards Of Memory** p14-DH1e-Inquisitor's Handbook
>
> Despite the best efforts of their mental
> conditioning, strange and disturbing flashes of the past may creep
> through, materialising in frozen dislocated images in dreams, sudden
> déjà-vu or inexplicable fears and revulsions that pass in a flickering
> panicked moment. Table 1-3: Shards of Memory presents a few possible
> examples (GMs may feel inclined to provide further “episodes”).

The rest of the page is home to a table of different possible memories, which may or may not express you character's actual past. I would work with your GM on this, as they are more likely to have an idea of how to tie-in your Shards of Memory with their plot, and it also gives you an opportunity to discuss your hopes/thoughts/ideas/theme.